# Trying to install package to my home directory results in error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux.  I don't have sudo and want to install a package to my home direcotry.  So I'm trying the below, but getting the error,

> "No matching distribution found for awscii"

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ pip install --user awscii
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting awscii
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awscii (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awscii
[myuser@mymachine ~]$
```

What is the proper way to install a python package to my home directory?

Comment: I think you have typo, it should be `awscli`

Comment: Also suggest you use `virtualenv` to install a newer version of Python.

Comment: @kiran.koduru, I don't have sudo access to my machine, how would I install virtualenv?

Comment: `pip install --user virtualenv` should work, no?

Answer (score 1):

The default `ec2-user` has sudo privileges so you should be able to upgrade your python version

```
$ sudo yum update
```

I think this only should even upgrade you to python27.

If not if you want to install python 27

```
$ sudo yum install python27
```

If you want to install python 3

```
$ sudo yum install python34
```